# Facebook PHP API - sudden problem with users_isAppUser()

Tags: php, facebook

we have an iframe facebookapp which worked fine till yesterday. Although we didn't change anything our app suddenly stopped working.

We could identify `users_isAppUser()` as a problem. The method returns that the user has not added the app though he definitely has installed the app and is logged in. We could delete the try/catch part (see code below), so that the app does not get catched in a redirect loop, but the following methods do not work either:

```
$this->facebook->api_client->friends_get()

$this->facebook->api_client->friends_getAppUsers()

$this->facebook->api_client->call_method('facebook.users.hasAppPermission', array('ext_perm' => 'publish_stream'))
```

`require_login()` does work and we can get the facebook userid of the logged in user.

The weird thing is, that our app worked fine for a couple of weeks till yesterday. 
**Have there been any secret changes to the API in the last days? Or any other conclusions what the problem could be? 
I would appreciate any tips. Thanks in advance!**

```
$this->fbuserid = $this->facebook->require_login();

// check if user has added app,  exception gets thrown if the cookie has an invalid session_key i.e. user is not logged in
try {
    if(!$this->facebook->api_client->users_isAppUser()) {
        $this->facebook->redirect($this->facebook->get_add_url());
    }
} catch (exception $ex) {
    // clear cookies for application and redirect to login prompt
    $this->facebook->set_user(null, null);
    $this->facebook->redirect($this->configArray['appcallbackurl']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// this is sample code taken from the Facebook Developers Site.Thank you to Face book

define('YOUR_APP_ID', '');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '');


function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);

  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);
echo "<pre/>";
/*print_r($_COOKIE);

print_r($cookie);*/
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']));

$photo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100000439661780/albums?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']));

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($photo);
?>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/ureshpatel5/picture" height="200" width="200" />
<html>
  <body>
  <?php
  $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
print_r($albums);
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
{
        // get all photos for album
        $photos = $facebook->api("/{189346844423303_46487}/photos");

        foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
        {
                echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
        }
}  
  ?>
    <?php if ($cookie) { ?>
      Welcome <?= $user->name ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        echo $photo->source;
     ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
               cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload(); 

      });
          </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the [Facebook example code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). Please do not copy & paste without attribution.

Comment: if these are your real keys, note that all versions of your answer are saved (click the "edited .... ago" link above) and publicly visible. If you need them gone completely, flag for a moderator's attention and ask them to remove the first revision. The same goes for your other answer where the key and secret are visible